# Set Xamarin.Forms Editor Height

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I wonder what's the code or property to set an Editor's height. I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Or at least how can I change the Editor's Height.

Answer (score 5):

Class Hierarchy:

`Editor` -> `InputView` -> `View` -> `VisualElement`

[VisualElement](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement/) has a `HeightRequest` Property

> Gets or sets the desired height override of this element.

See: [HeightRequest](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.HeightRequest/)